# About reductive Levi subalgebra of a parabolic subalgebra

Tags: lie-algebras

According to [Vinberg - Lie groups and invariant theory](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=6VqKgvUTncoC&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=Reductive%20Levi%20subalgebra&source=bl&ots=wNJg9BJSij&sig=ACfU3U09YIu7ObwPneZFC9LI4iy7JQ5JIg&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiaqOLeqY7iAhUZPXAKHa7XA9wQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Reductive%20Levi%20subalgebra&f=false), given a real or complex algebraic Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$, its reductive subalgebra $\mathfrak{r}$ is called a **reductive Levi subalgebra** of $\mathfrak{h}$ if $\mathfrak{h}$ is a semidirect product of $\mathfrak{r}$ and the **unipotent radical** $\mathrm{rad_u}\mathfrak{h}$.

I have googled the term unipotent radical and found out its definition is the maximal ideal whose elements are nilpotent. See [Popov - Algebraic transformation groups and algebraic varieties](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=_5Uxvjyc97EC&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=maximal%20ideal%20whose%20elements%20are%20nilpotent&source=bl&ots=GyV85TRYlp&sig=ACfU3U1iTSN2NCph3xw7Qcu_AqRZSnm0nA&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ9LO0ro7iAhUZa94KHZpPDYoQ6AEwC3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=maximal%20ideal%20whose%20elements%20are%20nilpotent&f=false).

According to [Es Saadi, Khakimdjanov, and Makhlouf - Standard subalgebras of semisimple Lie algebras and computer-aided for enumeration](http://www.numdam.org/article/AMBP_2003__10_2_315_0.pdf), we have $\rho$, a standard parabolic subalgebra of a finite dimensional semisimple complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, is a direct sum of a **reductive Levi subalgebra** of $\rho$ and the **nilradical** of $\rho$.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilradical_of_a_Lie_algebra), nilradical is the maximal nilpotent ideal.

**My question:**

1. Are the unipotent radical of $\rho$ and the nilradical of $\rho$ the same?
2. If yes to question 1, how to show the unipotent radical of $\rho$ is the same as the nilradical of $\rho$ by the definitions?

Comment: Your termonology and notation are rather nonstandard.    It's probably simpler to refer back to the early chapters of Bourbaki's treatise on Lie groups and Lie algebras, starting with Chapter 1 (which sorts out carefully the notions of radical).

Comment: As @JimHumphreys mentions, I think it is worth realising that the two meanings of 'nilpotent' here are different.  One is a property of abstract Lie algebras; the other is a property of an element of a Lie algebra that only makes sense with respect to a chosen representation (and is independent of that representation if there is a faithful one, as you are assuming).  Also, it's much more common to use $\mathfrak p$ than $\rho$ for a Lie algebra of a parabolic subgroup.

Comment: An ALA consisting of nilpotent elements may be faithfully represented inside some Lie algebra of strictly upper-triangular matrices, hence is nilpotent.  On the other hand, a nilpotent ideal (in the abstract sense) *need not* consist of nilpotent elements (in the algebraic sense); consider, for example, the case where $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak p$ is Abelian (so the answer to (1) is 'no').